# How can I handle invalid phone numbers using python's phonenumbers package and apply?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, libphonenumber

I have a dataframe containing a variety of phone numbers that I want to extract the time zone for.  I am apply to loop over the series in the dataframe as follows

```
external_calls_cleaned_df['time_zone'] = external_calls_cleaned_df.apply(lambda x: timezone.time_zones_for_number(phonenumbers.parse(str(x.external_number), None)), axis=1)
```

And this works just fine as long as the phone number in x.external_number doesn't contain a single invalid phone number; however, if one single invalid phone number is found in the entire series, it fails.

What I would like it to do is return 'Null' or None whenever it gets an invalid number- anything, actually - I can filter those out after the fact, but I don't want the process to stop at that point.

I have tried to wrap the timezone function in a new function and then execute it with try

```py
def get_timezone(df):
    try:
        x = timezone.time_zones_for_number(phonenumbers.parse(str(df.external_number), None))
    except:
       None
    return x
```

and then using

```
external_calls_cleaned_df['time_zone'] = external_calls_cleaned_df.apply(lambda x:get_timezone(x), axis=1)
```

The process completes then, but it fills the 'time_zone' field with None for every value.

To accomplish this I am using the phonenumbers package which is a port from the libphonenumber java package from google.

I can't share the phone numbers in my database for obvious reasons, so I don't know how to turn this into a reproducible example, or I would provide it.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks,
Brad

Comment: You can create dummy phone nu8mbers which illustrate the formatting variety and include numbers which produce your specific error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try refactoring your code in order to use [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with the target column "external_number" instead of [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with the whole dataframe, like this:

```py
def get_timezone(x):
    try:
        return timezone.time_zones_for_number(phonenumbers.parse(str(x), None))
    except:
        return None


external_calls_cleaned_df["time_zone"] = external_calls_cleaned_df[
    "external_number"
].map(get_timezone)
```